# How to find the size of virtual memory

Tags: memory, virtual-memory

If the size of the physical memory is given to us , can the size of the virtual memory be found out? If yes, then how?

Comment: With only the size of physical memory, no.  More information would be necessary.

Comment: VM for what?  One process? Max possible?

Comment: you can query the underlying os, but since you've provided not details whatsoever on how/where you need to do this, we can't help you.

Comment: i was asked in an interview that if the size of physical memory is 2^32-1 , what would be the size of the virtual memory?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on CPU and MotherBoard. More details you can find in Gustavo Duarte's [blog](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/memory-translation-and-segmentation/)

Answer (score 0):

No just by knowing the available RAM it is not possible to answer the question you were asked in your interview. let suppose you have 64 bit machine with 64 bit OS with 4/8/16... GB RAM. how RAM can tell the nature of OS and underlying machine. you must have at least some information about OS and architecture to give answer of the asked question

Answer (score 0):

The virtual memory depends upon a number of factors. These include:

1. The hardware limits.
2. Limits imposed by your operating system (usually system parameters).
3. Process quota limits.
4. Page file size.